# mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables and cannot select

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I have a problem I can not do select throw me the following error:

> Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_result(): Number of bind variables doesn't match number of fields in prepared statement in Login.php on line 19

This code:

```
$user = "user";
$pass = "pass";

$conn = new mysqli(MYSQL_HOST, MYSQL_USER,MYSQL_PASS,MYSQL_DB);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users where pass = ? and user = ?" ;

$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $user, $pass);

$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($userLogin);
$stmt->fetch();

echo $userLogin;
```

This is the table in MySQL

```
id  int(11) NO  PRI     auto_increment
user    varchar(45) NO  UNI     
pass    varchar(45) NO
```

I do not understand why the error

Answer (score 1):

`bind_result` binds **all** selected fields to variables. This means that if you select 3 fields from a table, you **must** provide 3 variables:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users where pass = ? and user = ?" ;

$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $user, $pass);

$stmt->execute();
// here - three fields are binded to three variables
$stmt->bind_result($userId, $userLogin, $userPass);
$stmt->fetch();
```

Or select only **required** field(s):

```
$sql = "SELECT user FROM users where pass = ? and user = ?" ;

$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $user, $pass);

$stmt->execute();
// here - one field is binded to one variable
$stmt->bind_result($userLogin);
$stmt->fetch();
```

And finally, you mix order of `bind_param` variables:

```
$sql = "SELECT user FROM users where pass = ? and user = ?" ;
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $pass, $user); // first - pass, second - user
```